# vba to check if each cell in a column is equal to a variable after filtering

Tags: vba, filter, count

```
Sub test_calculateval() 
    Dim rnData, r As Range, ThisYearID, LR, FR, EndR, HomeCount, AwayCount, DrawCount, i As Long, Hometeam As String 
    ThisYearID = Sheet5.Cells(2, 1).Value - 1 
    Hometeam = Sheet5.Cells(2, 5) 
    HomeCount = 0 
    With Sheet1
        Set rnData = Range(Range("A2"), Range("R2").End(xlDown))
        With rnData
            Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A2"), Range("R2").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & ThisYearID - 5
            ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A2"), Range("R2").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Hometeam
            LR = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:R" & LR).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            FR = r.Row
            EndR = Range("A" & FR).End(xlDown).Row 
            For Each rngarea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                If Range("K2:K" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "H" Then
                    HomeCount = HomeCount + 1
                End If 
            Next
        End With 
    End With 
    MsgBox HomeCount 
End Sub
```

I want to check if each cell in column K (after filtering) is equal to "H", and count them.
This code is throwing a type mismatch error, what seems to be the problem

Comment: Try debugging by pressing F8 and find out which line of code is causing the issue of type mismatch? Most probably an integer defined variable is being assigned a string value and VBA can't-do this conversion implicitly.

Comment: i think this one:
 For Each rngarea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                If Range("K2:K" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "H" Then
                    HomeCount = HomeCount + 1
                End If

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible that

```
    Range("K2:K" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

might be returning multiple cells, so it cannot be compared to a single string value. In simple words, we cannot calculate the value of multiple cells, when they are returned to a range. The solution applies a third filter to the filtered range which filters all the records having value "H" in the column K and then we count all the visible cells.

This code will turn out to be faster than doing the same thing via loops.

Replace this existing code with this one:

```
Sub test_calculateval() 
Dim rnData, r As Range, ThisYearID, LR, FR, EndR, HomeCount, AwayCount, DrawCount, i As Long, Hometeam As String 
ThisYearID = Sheet5.Cells(2, 1).Value - 1 
Hometeam = Sheet5.Cells(2, 5) 
HomeCount = 0 
With Sheet1
    Set rnData = Range(Range("A2"), Range("R2").End(xlDown))
    With rnData
        .AutoFilter 
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & ThisYearID - 5
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Hometeam
        .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=H", Operator:=xlAnd
        HomeCount = .Columns("K2:K" & (rnData.Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count-1
    End With 
End With 
MsgBox HomeCount
```

End Sub

Comment: it works, but it counts all the "H" in column K, not only the visible ones after filtering is applied.